# How to have a second image on top of another overflowing section?

Tags: html, image, css

I have a `section` with a responsive `absolute`  centered image inside:

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  background: url(images/passion__shape.png) top center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  top: -190px;
}
section > img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 85%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="images/img.png">
</section>
```

Now I'm trying to add a second (very wide) responsive image to this `section`. 
The right side of the new image should always be at the center of the existing image, like the following:

[image: SS]

I can't find a way to do that because the new image will shrink and change position if I use `max-width` or `max-height`.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: is the second wide responsive image you are referencing is `section > img` ?

Comment: no, it is a new image.

Comment: then what is `section > img`? Is it the A image and the new image is 'B' ??

Comment: section > img is the A image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform`:

```
section > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qtjyxxcv/)

Hope its solved! Let me know any issue.

Answer (score 1):

using `flexbox` with `align-items:center` to align vertically, + `position` with `calc()` you can achieve what you want

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}
section {
  position: relative;
  background: url("//dummyimage.com/500x500&text=bg") top center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}
.small {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 85%;
  width: auto;
}
.wide {
  position: relative;
  left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px green solid
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img class="small" src="//lorempixel.com/250/250" />
  <img class="wide" src="//placehold.it/500x250" />
</section>
```